# Automatic date dimension

Tags: ssis

I'm building my first DW with SSIS 2012. Currently I'm building my ETL process and populating my Dimension tables. One obvious dimension is the date dimension. Do I need to create this dimension myself or is there a way to generate this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be generated automatically as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174832.aspx

This is in Analysis Services though, but you do have the option to create it in the source database, which is probably what you want.

Otherwise, there are many scripts via searching such as this: http://sqldusty.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/create-date-dimension-script/

Answer (score 1):

This is the sqldusty script posted by @gbn with the formatting cleaned up.

```
--Make sure you set the Start and End Date below on row 58 and 59
--Create the tables
BEGIN TRY
DROP TABLE [DimDate]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
--DO NOTHING
END CATCH

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimDate](
--[DateSK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL--Use this line if you just want an autoincrementing counter AND COMMENT BELOW LINE
[DateSK] [int] NOT NULL--TO MAKE THE DateSK THE YYYYMMDD FORMAT USE THIS LINE AND COMMENT ABOVE LINE.
, [FullDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
, [Day] [tinyint] NOT NULL
, [DaySuffix] [varchar](4) NOT NULL
, [DayOfWeek] [varchar](9) NOT NULL
, [DayOfWeekNumber] [int] NOT NULL
, [DayOfWeekInMonth] [tinyint] NOT NULL
, [DayOfYearNumber] [int] NOT NULL
, [RelativeDays] int NOT NULL
, [WeekOfYearNumber] [tinyint] NOT NULL
, [WeekOfMonthNumber] [tinyint] NOT NULL
, [RelativeWeeks] int NOT NULL
, [CalendarMonthNumber] [tinyint] NOT NULL
, [CalendarMonthName] [varchar](9) NOT NULL
, [RelativeMonths] int NOT NULL
, [CalendarQuarterNumber] [tinyint] NOT NULL
, [CalendarQuarterName] [varchar](6) NOT NULL
, [RelativeQuarters] int NOT NULL
, [CalendarYearNumber] int NOT NULL
, [RelativeYears] int NOT NULL
, [StandardDate] [varchar](10) NULL
, [WeekDayFlag] bit NOT NULL
, [HolidayFlag] bit NOT NULL
, [OpenFlag] bit NOT NULL
, [FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag] bit NOT NULL
, [LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag] bit NOT NULL
, [HolidayText] [varchar](50) NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_DimDate] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[DateSK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

--Populate Date dimension

TRUNCATE TABLE DimDate

--IF YOU ARE USING THE YYYYMMDD format for the primary key then you need to comment out this line.
--DBCC CHECKIDENT (DimDate, RESEED, 60000) --In case you need to add earlier dates later.

DECLARE @tmpDOW TABLE (DOW INT, Cntr INT)--Table for counting DOW occurance in a month
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(1,0)--Used in the loop below
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(2,0)
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(3,0)
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(4,0)
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(5,0)
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(6,0)
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(7,0)

DECLARE @StartDate datetime
, @EndDate datetime
, @Date datetime
, @WDofMonth INT
, @CurrentMonth INT
, @CurrentDate date = getdate()

SELECT @StartDate = '1/1/2000'  -- -- Set The start and end date
, @EndDate = '1/01/2020'--Non inclusive. Stops on the day before this.
, @CurrentMonth = 1 --Counter used in loop below.

SELECT @Date = @StartDate

WHILE @Date < @EndDate
BEGIN

IF DATEPART(MONTH,@Date) <> @CurrentMonth
BEGIN
SELECT @CurrentMonth = DATEPART(MONTH,@Date)
UPDATE @tmpDOW SET Cntr = 0
END

UPDATE @tmpDOW
SET Cntr = Cntr + 1
WHERE DOW = DATEPART(DW,@DATE)

SELECT @WDofMonth = Cntr
FROM @tmpDOW
WHERE DOW = DATEPART(DW,@DATE)

INSERT INTO DimDate
(
[DateSK],       -- --TO MAKE THE DateSK THE YYYYMMDD FORMAT UNCOMMENT THIS LINE… Comment for autoincrementing.
[FullDate]
, [Day]
, [DaySuffix]
, [DayOfWeek]
, [DayOfWeekNumber]
, [DayOfWeekInMonth]
, [DayOfYearNumber]
, [RelativeDays]

, [WeekOfYearNumber]
, [WeekOfMonthNumber]
, [RelativeWeeks]

, [CalendarMonthNumber]
, [CalendarMonthName]
, [RelativeMonths]

, [CalendarQuarterNumber]
, [CalendarQuarterName]
, [RelativeQuarters]

, [CalendarYearNumber]
, [RelativeYears]

, [StandardDate]
, [WeekDayFlag]
, [HolidayFlag]
, [OpenFlag]
, [FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag]
, [LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag]

)

SELECT

CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Date,112), --TO MAKE THE DateSK THE YYYYMMDD FORMAT UNCOMMENT THIS LINE COMMENT FOR AUTOINCREMENT
@Date [FullDate]
, DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) [Day]
, CASE
WHEN DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) IN (11,12,13) THEN CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) + 'th'
WHEN RIGHT(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE),1) = 1 THEN CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) + 'st'
WHEN RIGHT(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE),1) = 2 THEN CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) + 'nd'
WHEN RIGHT(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE),1) = 3 THEN CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) + 'rd'
ELSE CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) + 'th'
END AS [DaySuffix]
, CASE DATEPART(DW, @DATE)
WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
WHEN 7 THEN 'Saturday'
END AS [DayOfWeek]
,DATEPART(DW, @DATE) AS [DayOfWeekNumber]
, @WDofMonth [DOWInMonth]--Occurance of this day in this month. If Third Monday then 3 and DOW would be Monday.
, DATEPART(dy,@Date) [DayOfYearNumber]--Day of the year. 0 -- 365/366
, DATEDIFF(dd,@CurrentDate,@Date) as [RelativeDays]

, DATEPART(ww,@Date) [WeekOfYearNumber]--0-52/53
, DATEPART(ww,@Date) + 1 -
DATEPART(ww,CAST(DATEPART(mm,@Date) AS VARCHAR) + '/1/' + CAST(DATEPART(yy,@Date) AS VARCHAR)) [WeekOfMonthNumber]
, DATEDIFF(ww,@CurrentDate,@Date) as [RelativeWeeks]

, DATEPART(MONTH,@DATE) as [CalendarMonthNumber] --To be converted with leading zero later.
, DATENAME(MONTH,@DATE) as [CalendarMonthName]
, DATEDIFF(MONTH,@CurrentDate,@Date) as [RelativeMonths]

, DATEPART(qq,@DATE) as [CalendarQuarterNumber] --Calendar quarter
, CASE DATEPART(qq,@DATE)
WHEN 1 THEN 'First'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Second'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Third'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Fourth'
END AS [CalendarQuarterName]
, DATEDIFF(qq,@CurrentDate,@Date) as [RelativeQuarters]

, DATEPART(YEAR,@Date) as [CalendarYearNumber]
, DATEDIFF(YEAR,@CurrentDate,@Date) as [RelativeYears]

, RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar(2),MONTH(@Date)),2) + '/' + Right('0' + convert(varchar(2),DAY(@Date)),2) + '/' + convert(varchar(4),YEAR(@Date))
, CASE DATEPART(DW, @DATE)
WHEN 1 THEN 0
WHEN 2 THEN 1
WHEN 3 THEN 1
WHEN 4 THEN 1
WHEN 5 THEN 1
WHEN 6 THEN 1
WHEN 7 THEN 0
END AS [WeekDayFlag]

, 0 as HolidayFlag

, CASE DATEPART(DW, @DATE)
WHEN 1 THEN 0
WHEN 2 THEN 1
WHEN 3 THEN 1
WHEN 4 THEN 1
WHEN 5 THEN 1
WHEN 6 THEN 1
WHEN 7 THEN 1
END AS OpenFlag

, CASE DATEPART(dd,@Date)
WHEN 1
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END as [FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag]

, CASE
WHEN DateAdd(day, -1, DateAdd( month, DateDiff(month , 0,@Date)+1 , 0)) = @Date
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END as [LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag]

SELECT @Date = DATEADD(dd,1,@Date)
END

--Add HOLIDAYS --------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- New Years Day --------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'New Year”s Day',
HolidayFlag = 1,
OpenFlag = 0
WHERE [CalendarMonthNumber] = 1 AND [DAY] = 1
--Set OpenFlag = 0 if New Year's Day is on weekend
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET OpenFlag = 0
WHERE DateSK in
(Select CASE
WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Sunday'
THEN DATESK + 1
END
FRom DimDate
where CalendarMonthNumber = 1
and [DAY] = 1)

--Martin Luther King Day ----------------------------------------------------------
--Third Monday in January starting in 1983
UPDATE DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Martin Luther King Jr. Day',
HolidayFlag = 1,
OpenFlag = 0
WHERE [CalendarMonthNumber] = 1--January
AND [Dayofweek] = 'Monday'
AND CalendarYearNumber >= 1983--When holiday was official
AND [DayOfWeekInMonth] = 3--Third X day of current month.
GO

--President's Day ----------------------------------------------------------
--Third Monday in February.
UPDATE DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'President”s Day',
HolidayFlag = 1,
OpenFlag = 0
WHERE [CalendarMonthNumber] = 2--February
AND [Dayofweek] = 'Monday'
AND [DayOfWeekInMonth] = 3--Third occurance of a monday in this month.
GO

--Memorial Day -----------------------------------------------------------
--Last Monday in May
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Memorial Day',
HolidayFlag = 1,
OpenFlag = 0
FROM DimDate
WHERE DateSK IN
(
SELECT MAX([DateSK])
FROM dbo.DimDate
WHERE [CalendarMonthName] = 'May'
AND [DayOfWeek] = 'Monday'
GROUP BY CalendarYearNumber, [CalendarMonthNumber]
)

--4th of July --------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Independance Day',
HolidayFlag = 1,
OpenFlag = 0
WHERE [CalendarMonthNumber] = 7 AND [DAY] = 4
--Set OpenFlag = 0 if July 4th is on weekend
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET OpenFlag = 0
WHERE DateSK in
(Select CASE
WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Sunday'
THEN DATESK + 1
END
FRom DimDate
where CalendarMonthNumber = 7
and [DAY] = 4)

--Labor Day -------------------------------------------------------------
--First Monday in September
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Labor Day',
HolidayFlag = 1,
OpenFlag = 0
FROM DimDate
WHERE DateSK IN
(
SELECT MIN([DateSK])
FROM dbo.DimDate
WHERE [CalendarMonthName] = 'September'
AND [DayOfWeek] = 'Monday'
GROUP BY CalendarYearNumber, [CalendarMonthNumber]
)

--Columbus Day------------------------------------------------------------
--2nd Monday in October
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Columbus Day',
HolidayFlag = 1,
OpenFlag = 0
FROM DimDate
WHERE DateSK IN
(
SELECT MIN(DateSK)
FROM dbo.DimDate
WHERE [CalendarMonthName] = 'October'
AND [DayOfWeek] = 'Monday'
AND [DayOfWeekInMonth] = 2
GROUP BY CalendarYearNumber,
[CalendarMonthNumber]
)

--Veteran's Day --------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Veteran”s Day',
HolidayFlag = 1,
OpenFlag = 0
WHERE DateSK in (
Select CASE
WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Saturday'
THEN DateSK -- 1
WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Sunday'
THEN DateSK + 1
ELSE DateSK
END as VeteransDateSK
FROM DimDate
WHERE [CalendarMonthNumber]  = 11
AND [DAY] = 11)
GO

--THANKSGIVING --------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Fourth THURSDAY in November.
UPDATE DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Thanksgiving Day',
HolidayFlag = 1,
OpenFlag = 0
WHERE [CalendarMonthNumber] = 11
AND [DAYOFWEEK] = 'Thursday'
AND [DayOfWeekInMonth] = 4
GO

--CHRISTMAS -------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Christmas Day',
HolidayFlag = 1,
OpenFlag = 0
WHERE [CalendarMonthNumber] = 12 AND [DAY] = 25
--Set OpenFlag = 0 if Christmas on weekend
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET OpenFlag = 0
WHERE DateSK in
(Select CASE
WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Sunday'
THEN DATESK + 1
WHEN Dayofweek = 'Saturday'
THEN DateSK -- 1
END
FRom DimDate
where CalendarMonthNumber = 12
and DAY = 25)

-- Valentine's Day --------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Valentine”s Day'
WHERE CalendarMonthNumber = 2 AND [DAY] = 14

-- Saint Patrick's Day ------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Saint Patrick”s Day'
WHERE [CalendarMonthNumber] = 3 AND [DAY] = 17
GO

--Mother's Day ----------------------------------------------------------
--Second Sunday of May
UPDATE DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Mother”s Day'--select * from DimDate
WHERE [CalendarMonthNumber] = 5--May
AND [Dayofweek] = 'Sunday'
AND [DayOfWeekInMonth] = 2--Second occurance of a monday in this month.
GO
--Father's Day ----------------------------------------------------------
--Third Sunday of June
UPDATE DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Father”s Day'--select * from DimDate
WHERE [CalendarMonthNumber] = 6--June
AND [Dayofweek] = 'Sunday'
AND [DayOfWeekInMonth] = 3--Third occurance of a monday in this month.
GO
--Halloween 10/31 -------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Halloween'
WHERE [CalendarMonthNumber] = 10 AND [DAY] = 31
--Election Day----------------------------------------------------------
--The first Tuesday after the first Monday in November.
BEGIN TRY
drop table #tmpHoliday
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
--do nothing
END CATCH

CREATE TABLE #tmpHoliday(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), DateID int, Week TINYINT, YEAR CHAR(4), DAY CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO #tmpHoliday(DateID, [YEAR],[DAY])
SELECT [DateSK], CalendarYearNumber, [DAY]
FROM dbo.DimDate
WHERE [CalendarMonthNumber] = 11
AND [Dayofweek] = 'Monday'
ORDER BY CalendarYearNumber, [DAY]

DECLARE @CNTR INT, @POS INT, @STARTYEAR INT, @ENDYEAR INT, @CURRENTYEAR INT, @MINDAY INT

SELECT @CURRENTYEAR = MIN([YEAR])
, @STARTYEAR = MIN([YEAR])
, @ENDYEAR = MAX([YEAR])
FROM #tmpHoliday

WHILE @CURRENTYEAR <= @ENDYEAR
BEGIN
SELECT @CNTR = COUNT([YEAR])
FROM #tmpHoliday
WHERE [YEAR] = @CURRENTYEAR

SET @POS = 1

WHILE @POS <= @CNTR
BEGIN
SELECT @MINDAY = MIN(DAY)
FROM #tmpHoliday
WHERE [YEAR] = @CURRENTYEAR
AND [WEEK] IS NULL

UPDATE #tmpHoliday
SET [WEEK] = @POS
WHERE [YEAR] = @CURRENTYEAR
AND [DAY] = @MINDAY

SELECT @POS = @POS + 1
END

SELECT @CURRENTYEAR = @CURRENTYEAR + 1
END

UPDATE DT
SET HolidayText = 'Election Day'
FROM dbo.DimDate DT
JOIN #tmpHoliday HL
ON (HL.DateID + 1) = DT.DateSK
WHERE [WEEK] = 1

DROP TABLE #tmpHoliday
GO
----------------------------------------------------------------------
PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),113)--USED FOR CHECKING RUN TIME.

--DimDate indexes--------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_Date] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[FullDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_Day] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[Day] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_DayOfWeek] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[DayOfWeek] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_DOWInMonth] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[DayOfWeekInMonth] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_DayOfYear] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[DayOfYearNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_WeekOfYear] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[WeekOfYearNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_WeekOfMonth] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[WeekOfMonthNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_Month] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[CalendarMonthNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_MonthName] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[CalendarMonthName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_Quarter] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[CalendarQuarterNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_QuarterName] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[CalendarQuarterName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_Year] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[CalendarYearNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_dim_Time_HolidayText] ON [dbo].[DimDate]
(
[HolidayText] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

PRINT convert(varchar,getdate(),113)--USED FOR CHECKING RUN TIME.
```